# Rendering props to Wrapped Component when using HOC in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was looking at the react documentation for Higher-Order Components and I stumbled upon an example where you can log props, for a specific component

```
function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
return class extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      console.log('Current props: ', this.props);
      console.log('Next props: ', nextProps);
    }
    render() {
      // Wraps the input component in a container, without mutating it. Good!
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
}
```

when you render the component is there a difference between inserting

```
{...this.props}
```

and

```
{props.children}
```

they would both essentially return the given props to the component, is there a best practice or a specific use case where when is better than the other?

From the react docs about props.children

```
 you can use props.children on components that represent ‘generic boxes’ and that ‘don’t know their children ahead of time’.
```

to me this seems like the same use case as in {...this.props}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{...this.props}` and `props.children` are used for achieving different objectives.

`{...this.props}` is used so that all the props given to this specific component are [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) onto another. Taking an example from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes):

```
function App1() {
  return <Greeting firstName="Ben" lastName="Hector" />;
}

function App2() {
  const props = {firstName: 'Ben', lastName: 'Hector'};
  return <Greeting {...props} />;
}
```

These two cases have the same results. So, `spread` is best approach for passing on props from an HOC.

`props.children` on the other hand is used to pass on children to another component. This is one specific `prop` that React assigns that you cannot explicitly find among attributes. This prop is present inside the opening and closing tag of a component. Another example from [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx):

```
<MyComponent>Hello world!</MyComponent>

// Can be used in the component as:
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>{props.children}</div>
  );
}
```

Here, `MyComponent` will emit `<div>Hello World</div>` to the DOM.

Comment: Precise answer, Thank you for clarifying that